# (WPF) DevExpress mvvm + Castle Windsor. How to build POCO viewmodels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, castle-windsor

In the DevExpress MVVM framework, you can define both standard ViewModels, inheriting from ViewModelBase. Or, you can define POCO ViewModels ([see this link](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/wpf/archive/2013/12/04/devexpress-mvvm-framework-introduction-to-poco-viewmodels.aspx)), that are better and more sophisticated.

To build such a "POCO" view model, you **must** use the **ViewModelSource** util. This will kind of make a standard dummy class into a POCO ViewModel.

```
namespace DataAbstractWPF.ViewModels
{
    [POCOViewModel]
    public class EntityKindViewModel : Interfaces.ICreateEntityKindViewModel
    {
    }
}
```

Then, in XAML, to instantiate or define such a POCO viewmodel, you must :

```
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm" 
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:DataAbstractWPF.ViewModels"
         d:DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource ViewModels:CreateEntityWizardViewModel}"
```

If you pass the ViewModel to the View dynamically or simply

```
         xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm" 
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:DataAbstractWPF.ViewModels"
         DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource ViewModels:CreateEntityWizardViewModel}"
```

If you want the ViewModel to be instantiated directly by the XAML.

You can also create it by code

```
ViewModelSource.Create<LoginViewModel>();
```

Or by a factory that can be created by the framework.

```
var factory = ViewModelSource.Factory((string caption) => new LoginViewModel(caption));
factory("Login");
```

Now, using Castle Windsor, I register this :

```
container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.ICreateEntityKindViewModel>().ImplementedBy<ViewModels.EntityKindViewModel>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.ICreateEntityWizardViewModel>().ImplementedBy<ViewModels.CreateEntityWizardViewModel>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.IMainWindowViewModel>().ImplementedBy<ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel>().LifestyleTransient());

container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.ICreateEntityWizard>().ImplementedBy<Views.CreateEntityWizard>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.IMainWindow>().ImplementedBy<Views.MainWindow>().LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.ICreateEntityKind>().ImplementedBy<Views.EntityKind>().LifestyleTransient());

container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.IShell>().ImplementedBy<Shell>().LifestyleTransient());
```

But now, of course, the **ViewModelSource** is completely bypassed, and the once beautiful POCO viewmodel is now merely a dummy useless object.

Now, my question is, how is it possible to use both ViewModelSource to create the POCO viewModels, and allow them to be injected by Castle Windsor ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this :

Create this helper class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataAbstractWPF.Helpers
{
    public class AttributeHelper
    {

        public static bool HasAttribute(Type implementation, Type attr)
        {
            object[] arr = implementation.GetCustomAttributes(true);
            List<object> list = new List<object>(arr);
            object attrib = list.Find(delegate (object o) { return ( attr.IsAssignableFrom(o.GetType()) ); });
            return attrib != null;
        }

    }
}
```

Create a component activator

```
using System;
using Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentActivator;
using DevExpress.Mvvm.DataAnnotations;
using DevExpress.Mvvm.Native;
using DataAbstractWPF.Helpers;

namespace DataAbstractWPF.Activators
{
    class DXViewModelActivator : DefaultComponentActivator
    {
        public DXViewModelActivator(Castle.Core.ComponentModel model, Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal kernel, Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentInstanceDelegate onCreation, Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentInstanceDelegate onDestruction)
            : base(model, kernel, onCreation, onDestruction)
        {
            Model.Implementation = TryGetPOCOType(Model.Implementation);
        }

        Type TryGetPOCOType(Type implementation)
        {
            if (AttributeHelper.HasAttribute(implementation, typeof(POCOViewModelAttribute)))
                implementation = ViewModelSourceHelper.GetProxyType(implementation);

            return implementation;
        }

    }
}
```

Create an installer like so

```
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration;
using Castle.Windsor;
using DataAbstractWPF.Helpers;
using DevExpress.Mvvm.DataAnnotations;
using DataAbstractWPF.Activators;

namespace DataAbstractWPF.Bootstrapping
{
    public class Installers : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {

            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .Where(type => AttributeHelper.HasAttribute(type, typeof(POCOViewModelAttribute)))
                .Configure(r => r.Activator<DXViewModelActivator>())
                .LifestyleTransient()
                .WithServiceDefaultInterfaces()
                );

            container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.ICreateEntityWizard>().ImplementedBy<Views.CreateEntityWizard>().LifestyleTransient());
            container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.IMainWindow>().ImplementedBy<Views.MainWindow>().LifestyleTransient());
            container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.ICreateEntityKind>().ImplementedBy<Views.CreateEntityKind>().LifestyleTransient());

            container.Register(Component.For<Interfaces.IShell>().ImplementedBy<Shell>().LifestyleTransient());
        }

    }
}
```

And now in your constructors, the dependencies will be resolved.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, Interfaces.IMainWindow
{ 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(Interfaces.IMainWindowViewModel context)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = context;
    }
}
```